# vs code access denied cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, access-denied

I am trying to setup my Vscode and this is the code I have written so far. But it says access denied.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define OJ \
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin); \
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);

int main()
{
    OJ;
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
 }
```

This is the error shown :

```
Program 'sample.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:93
+ ... scode\" ; if ($?) { g++ sample.cpp -o sample } ; if ($?) { .\sample }
+                                                                ~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:93
+ ... scode\" ; if ($?) { g++ sample.cpp -o sample } ; if ($?) { .\sample }
+                                                                ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Comment: don't use `bits/stdc++.h`

Comment: That `OJ` macro is all kinds of bad - don't use freopen and don't try to change stdin and stdout. 
Just open the files directly like `std::ifstream fin("input.txt"); fin >> a; std::ofstream fout("output.txt"); fout << a;`

Comment: I know a lot of acronyms but OJ is unknown (?? OJ Simpson, Orange Juice??), why do you do `#define` instead of a function